# F# return size of input defined as number of constructors

Tags: f#

beginner f# programmer here.

So basically I'm totally lost.  I've been staring at this question for the past hour not even knowing how to set up the first line of the let argument.  This question is asking to use pattern matching define a recursive function size : expr -> int that returns the size of its input expression denfied as the number of constructors from type expr in the expression

This is the recursive function:

```
size : expr -> int
```

Here are the constructors:

```
type oper = Neg | Not | Add | Mul | Sub | Less | Eq | And

type expr =
    | C of int
    | Op1 of oper * expr
    | Op2 of oper * expr * expr
    | If of expr * expr * expr
```

for example,

```
size(C 4)
```

would return 1

and

```
size (IF (C 4, Op2 (Add, C 1, C 2), C ())
```

would return 6

UPDATED AFTER SUGGESTION: IN PROGRESS!!

```
let rec size (e : expr) : int = 
    match e with
    | C i -> 1
    | Op1 (o, e1) -> size e1 + 1
    | Op2 (o, e1, e2)-> size e2 + 1
    | If (e1, e2, e3) -> size e3 + 1
```

Comment: Deleting the bit about o should be about what you want

Comment: The function type is `expr -> int`, which means that it should take *one* parameter, of type `expr`, and return an `int`. So far you've defined a function that takes *two* parameters, an `expr` and an `oper`. You don't actually need that second parameter. The `expr` type carries the operators around as data; if you have an `expr`, you can get at any `oper` values inside it by using a match pattern. I.e. `match thisExpr with | Op1 (o,e) -> ...` and now you have a variable `o` that is the `oper` inside `thisExpr`.

Comment: One more hint for once you start writing your function. When writing a recursive function like `size`, you can sometimes get stuck on "Okay, I need to call my `size` function here... but since I haven't written it yet, how do I know what it's going to return?" The best way to get unstuck is to **pretend you've written the function already**, so you already know what it's going to return -- and then use that function. I.e., if you have an `Op1` you know its size will be the size of its contained `expr`, plus 1. And what can tell you its size? The `size` function you're writing!

Comment: @rmunn and john palmer thank you for responding.  That's what we had at first but now I'm going to edit my OP and show what I have now.

Comment: Hint: you don't actually want a counter variable

Comment: @rmunn could you help guide me in the direction of this problem.  You've helped me in previous problems and have been a lot of help to me in learning f#!

Comment: also @JohnPalmer if you could that would be great as well.

Comment: @user2744489 - My last comment, plus John Palmer's mentioning that you don't need a counter variable, are about as much guidance as I can give you without basically doing this homework assignment for you. I told you how to write the `Op1` case; extrapolate from there to the other cases and you'll be done. If I gave you any more guidance right now I'd be doing you a disservice.

Comment: @rmunn ok i completely understand.  with that line you gave me.  Op1 (o, e1) -> size(e:expr) + 1 be it?

Comment: @rmunn I'm going to edit what I have in OP

Comment: That looks pretty good, but: 1) you don't need to specify the type of the parameter, because F# can work it out for you, and 2) you want to recursively call `size` with the *sub-expression*, not call it again with the original expression. In other words, calling `size(e)` as you're doing would create an infinite loop of recursion. What you want is to call `size(e1)` here.

Comment: One more comment: in F#, parentheses around function arguments usually aren't needed. `size(e1) + 1` can be `size e1 + 1`. Function calls have higher precedence than the `+` operator, so that works out to the same thing — but between two equivalent expressions, experienced F# programmers will usually prefer the version with fewer parentheses, as it usually turns out to be easier to read.

Comment: Your StackOverflowException (exception, not exemption) is because of that infinite loop of recursion that I mentioned. Any time you see "stack overflow", it's because you have too many recursive calls "stacked up" on top of each other before they return. Look at the function you wrote that calls `size(e)` and try tracing it in your head: will it ever return, or will it just keep calling itself over and over again? There's a limit to how many recursive calls F# will allow you to "stack up", so that it can prevent infinite loops like the one you accidentally wrote.

Comment: @rmunn i understand what you are saying,  but how do i pass back in how many steps?  Since in the end if It hits a Constant it should just return 1, but I know that is not right.

Comment: First, why do you think that returning 1 if it hits a Constant isn't right? It looks exactly right to me: in the expression `C 5`, there is precisely one constructor, the `C`. Second, in the `Op2` case, you need to take the size of `e1` *and* the size of `e2`; you can't just ignore `e1`. Now think about what the size of `Op2` would be, as a formula based on the size of the two subexpressions. How would you write that formula?

Comment: @rmunn  after messing around I found out how to do it.  I confuse myself multiple times

Comment: @rmunn thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: @user2744489 you can post your answer and even accept it if you like it.

Comment: @s952163 - Since this is a homework problem, I'd actually recommend against the OP posting his answer -- because then other people in his class could just Google the homework problem and find a ready-written answer, and then they wouldn't learn anything. That's precisely why I've been avoiding just giving him an answer, and instead giving him subtle hints.

Comment: @rmunn I wholeheartedly agree. But it can be googled anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'll summarize the hints that you were given in the comments, so that others who find this question can see that it was answered and that you were able to solve the problem:

1. Your original code didn't need a parameter of type `oper`; a single parameter of type `expr` was enough.
2. You don't need a mutable counter variable; recursion will serve you better.
3. When writing a recursive function like `size`, you can sometimes get stuck on "Okay, I need to call my `size` function here... but since I haven't written it yet, how do I know what it's going to return?" The best way to get unstuck is to pretend you've **written the function already**, so you already know what it's going to return -- and then use that function. And magically, it all works out: by the time you've finished the function, the function that it was calling (itself) is finished too! Funny how that works out. :-)
4. At one point you had a function that looked like this:

   ```
   let rec size (e : expr) : int = 
       match e with
       | C i -> 1
       | Op1 (o, e1) -> size e + 1
       // Rest of function omitted
   ```

   That was giving you a StackOverflowException, because calling `size e` inside the `Op1` match case was an infinite recursion loop. Hint: trace that call mentally, and think about the steps it would go through. It would check `e` against `Op1`, and call `size e` for the second time. That call would check `e` against `Op1`, and call `size e` for the third time. Would that ever terminate? Would those calls every do anything different from the previous calls, or would they keep looping "forever" until the function stack runs out of space?
5. Finally, in the cases where you have two or three `expr` variables, you need to deal with all of them, not just one.